# How to fade in/out a counter in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

So I have a bunch of divs that each contain a number. I am trying to set up a counter where it counts like this:

```
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
4 5 1
1 2 3
```

And so on. You can see my current code for this -   [here on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mirzar/2Q3mN/).

I am trying to get the nodes to fadeIn and fadeOut one node at a time instead of show/hiding the entire container.

Comment: IMO there's a little too much code for something so simple. http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3mN/1/ Adding effects should be a breeze then. http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3mN/2/

Comment: ps. The re-usable code without using a fixed height container: http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3mN/3/ too tired to write up an answer so best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
//I didn't wrap the roller inside a function for this example, but you can pass
//these values as arguments to a function instead of assigning them here:
var $slides = $('#slides'),
    n = 3; //number of visible children (`.speaker`)

//init by hiding the children with index larger than `n`
$slides.children(':gt('+(n-1)+')').hide();

//note that :eq and :gt are 0-based, hence the n-1. You could also assign
//n -= 1 or n-- after receiving the n parameter if using a function wrapper
setInterval(function () {
    $slides.children(':first').fadeOut(600, function () {
        $slides.append(this).children(':eq('+(n-1)+')').fadeIn(600);
    });
}, 1500);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q3mN/4/)

Comment: Thanks so much. Your method is a lot cleaner then my original way.